# Add eventlistener to a window in Titanium Mobile commonJS

Tags: events, mobile, titanium, listener, commonjs

I have a surely somehow stupid problem with adding an eventlistener to a window I create in a commonJS module in Titanium Mobile.

Consider i.e. the following code:

```
var SegmentListWindow = function(){
  var window = S.ui.createWindow("Testwindow");
  window.addEventListener("app:customListener", function(){ doSomething();});
  return window;
}
exports.SegmentListWindow = SegmentListWindow;
```

The window is nicely generated using

```
var Window = require(".....").SegmentListWindow;
var win = new Window();
```

`S.ui` is just a simple helper method to create some standard window in my app.

But the event listener is never called, I try`Ti.App.fireEvent("app:customListener"),` but the event doesn't reach the listener.
Only when Using `Ti.App.addEventListener` and adding a `global eventlistener` it's working.

I think maybe that problem is I am not adding the event listener to the `"instance"` of the window? But how to fix this? I don't want to add the `event listener` manually when instantiating the window somewhere in the app. Can't I do this in the commonJS module?

Answer (score 1):

Well, that really was a simple question.

I am doing a `Ti.App.fireEvent`, but was listening for `window.addEventListener`, that couldn't work.

Now I am doing the following:

Adding an eventlistener on window instantiation to the global `Ti.App`-Object, and remove this listener on the window's close event.
That works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You could also define the `SegmentListWindow` as you did in the question:

```js
var SegmentListWindow = function(){
  var window = Ti.UI.createWindow({title:"Testwindow"});
  window.addEventListener("win:customListener", function(){ doSomething();});
  return window;
}
exports.SegmentListWindow = SegmentListWindow;
```

and then fire the event on the `win` object:

```js
var Window = require(".....").SegmentListWindow;
var win = new Window();
win.fireEvent('win:customListener');
```